# SSRS used to send emails in Sharepoint app farm: can Reporting Server Configuration Manager support site specific email senders?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

my company uses Sharepoint 2016 server in an app farm configuration to allow different site collections to be hosted on a single farm.

the app farm has SSRS BI reporting configured to allow data connections to Sql Server.

what is nagging is emails generated by all SSRS subscription reports from all the different sites on the farm is seen as coming from the same sender address.

report 1
site 1: spappfarm.acme.com/site1
from: sharepoint@acme.com

report 2
site 2: spappfarm.acme.com/site2
from: sharepoint@acme.com

so can the from email field be changed in Report Server Configuration Manager that allows every site on the farm to use a different sender address?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

appears that the SSRS Configuration Manager only supports 1 sender address.
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-reporting-service-configuration-manager/